# Install ubuntu 16.04 on existing xubuntu 16.04 without losing data

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, xubuntu

I want to install ubuntu 16.04 on a partition where my xubuntu 16.04 is installed (I followed the installation process with this and I have a /home and / partitions).

Is it safe to install ubuntu 16.04 in the existing xubuntu without losing my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install it mount the previous partition on the same location uncheck format option.

[image]

Comment: what will happen to my Xubuntu? Will it be removed?

Comment: yes, it will get removed and you will lose your installed application and software.